# Parameterize the element being passed

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

I am using pageobjects and want to parameterize the element being passed.

Below step works fine:

```
text_field(:username, :id => "loginUserName")

And(/^I enter (.*) for username in LoginPage$/) do |data, actual_field|
  on_page @current_page do |page|
    page.username_element.set data
  end
```

But I want to parameterize the element name:

```
And(/^I enter (.*) for (.*) in LoginPage$/) do |data, actual_field|
  on_page @current_page do |page|
    page.get_element(actual_field).set data
  end
```

What method should I write to return `username_element`

```
def get_element(element_name)
  return "#{element_name}+'_element'"
end
```

This method returned string "username_element" so it doesnt work.

Any suggestions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `send` method to call a method based on a String:

```
page.send("#{actual_field}_element").set data
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what the follow-up question is that you are asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: And(/^I enter (.*) for (.*) $/) do |data, actual_field| 

on_page @current_page do |page| page.get_element(actual_field).set data 
end 
end 

    Given As a user I see LoginPage
    And I enter "name" for username in LoginPage
    And I enter "password123" for password in LoginPage

This worked for the first element on page. But for second element ie..password field it fails with below reason
undefined method `params' for #<LoginPage:0x3f2ddec9>

@current_page returns LoginPage first time...second element it returned #<LoginPage:0x49b7bb1f>

Comment: It might help if you put together a complete script that reproduces the problem.